# Jquery Isotope - make items always expand to same position

Tags: jquery, jquery-isotope

I am using the jquery isotope to develop a gallery of images, and when the user clicks on the thumbnail of the image it will expand, as seen in the isotope examples (http://isotope.metafizzy.co/demos/elements-complete.html)

The problem I'm having though is that I want every image to expand to the same position, i.e always expand to the very top left of the page, regardless of what thumbnail is clicked on.

I have played around and I can make the image appear expanded top left by adding the following code, but when I do it expands over the top of some of the thumbnail images.

```
$(this).css({"-webkit-transform": "translate3d(5px, 5px, 0px)"});
```

Here is what I have so far... http://jsfiddle.net/supersav144/f33UW/

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Think the last line of the js might be causing the problem.. Try this.. haven't tested for various container sizes tho.. http://jsfiddle.net/H5jYh/

```
    $container
  // update sort data on changed items
  .isotope('updateSortData', $this )
  .isotope('updateSortData', $previousLargeItem )
  // trigger layout and sort
  .isotope('reLayout');
```